# How to determine changes in filesystem due to new package installation

Tags: linux, macos, installation-package

Is it possible in OS X or Linux to determine what changes a particular operation has caused in the file system?

My usage case is this: I'm installing a dozen packages which are prerequisites for another package.

Some of them should not be necessary. I don't understand why I need all of them. So I would like to see exactly what each package does: which files it adds, Which files it modifies, which files it removes (although this should be none).

How do I do this?

Comment: I imagine a command or script that finds all files with a modification time after the beginning of your install could help.

Answer (score 1):

In .rpm based linux system the `rpm` utility is your friend. I don't have a suggestion for .deb based Linux nor suggestion for OS X.

To check what scripts are ran by specific package you can use the option `--scripts` and `--triggers` to see what the package did.

`rpm -q --scripts packagename`

Example:

```
rpm -q --scripts initscripts
preinstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 22 -r -f utmp
postinstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
touch /var/log/wtmp /var/run/utmp /var/log/btmp
chown root:utmp /var/log/wtmp /var/run/utmp /var/log/btmp
chmod 664 /var/log/wtmp /var/run/utmp
chmod 600 /var/log/btmp

/sbin/chkconfig --add netfs
/sbin/chkconfig --add network
/sbin/chkconfig --add netconsole
/sbin/chkconfig --add rawdevices
preuninstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
if [ $1 = 0 ]; then
  /sbin/chkconfig --del netfs
  /sbin/chkconfig --del network
  /sbin/chkconfig --del netconsole
  /sbin/chkconfig --del rawdevices
fi

rpm -q --triggers initscripts
triggerun scriptlet (using /bin/sh) -- initscripts < 7.62
/sbin/chkconfig --del random
exit 0
```

To check the list of files it saved on your system, use the `-l` option

```
rpm -ql packagename
```

Comment: RPM is not a part of the Mac OS X ecosystem.